# apache beam pipeline late data confusion with kafka -> s3 pipeline

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, spark-structured-streaming

I have a set of Apache Beam pipelines which read from a Kafka topic, deserialize the Protobuf model to Python object, and then write to S3 as Parquet in batches.

We have an existing Spark Structured Streaming app that performs a similar action that we are deprecating in favor of Beam/Flink.

We have our pipeline set up with a FixedWindow of 60 seconds and our `allowed_lateness` is set to 12 hours.

We are seeing discrepencies between our existing Spark-based approach vs our new, Beam approach.

Here's some snippets of code for the pipeline:

```py
def add_timestamp(event: Any) -> Any:
    # for some reason, we have to import the library here, otherwise beam will complain on undefined variable
    import time

    from apache_beam import window

    return window.TimestampedValue(event, time.time())
```

This is a section of our pipeline where we are adding a timestamp using the Beam processing timestamp, so we would expect there shouldn't be any late data at all.

```py
            inputs["input_data"]
            | "Adding 'trigger_processing_time' timestamp" >> beam.Map(add_timestamp)
            | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
            >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.FixedWindows(fixed_window_size),
                allowed_lateness=beam.utils.timestamp.Duration(allowed_lateness),
            )
```

Would someone be able to provide suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: I've not used Beam for this. Was there a reason to use that instead of Kafka Connect or Secor project?